# loop through multiple folders and perform commands then write to file

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I have 10 folders that I want to loop through while executing the following command:

> `awk 'FNR > 1' *.csv | sort -sk 1,2 | sort -sk 3,3 > ${f}_appended.dat`

With a for loop wrapper, like this:

```
for f in */ ; do awk 'FNR > 1' *.csv | sort -sk 1,2 | sort -sk 3,3 > ${f}_appended.dat; done
```

It only writes `_appended.dat` in each folder and does not perform the command on files in the folder it is looping through, but rather the root folder (if there are any).

**DESIRED OUTCOME:**

Have an _appended.dat file in each folder that was generated with the awk command. So 10 folders with a unique file generated based on the contents of .csv files in each folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will run the `awk` command on the `*.csv` files in each subdirectory, leaving behind a `{dirname}_appended.dat` file in that directory containing the output:

```sh
for f in */
do
    awk 'FNR > 1' "$f"/*.csv | sort -sk 1,2 | sort -sk 3,3 >"${f}${f%/}_appended.dat"
done
```

#### Discussion

Consider:

```
for f in */ ; do awk 'FNR > 1' *.csv | sort -sk 1,2 | sort -sk 3,3 > ${f}_appended.dat; done
```

On every run through the loop, this processes the `*.csv` files in the current directory.  To get the files in the `$f` directory, use `"$f"/*.csv` in place of `*.csv`.

Also, the above puts the results of each run in the file `${f}_appended.dat`

#### Alternative

Another approach is to `cd` into each directory and run the `awk` command:

```sh
for f in */
do
    ( cd "$f"; awk 'FNR > 1' *.csv | sort -sk 1,2 | sort -sk 3,3 >"${f%/}_appended.dat" )
done
```

The `cd` command is run inside a subshell (delimited by parentheses).  Consequently, the current directory is restored to its original value as soon as the subshell exits.

Comment: The files were already going into the respective directories, but I could not get them named with that directory as a prefix. Your solutions do not provide the desired outcome either, though they do offer me insight into the use of quotes and parentheses in calling variables. In fact, the only difference between your suggestion and my original code is putting quotes around the $f variable ahead of the *.csv files. That definitely pointed the control to _where_ the files to append are, but I still cannot get the directory to be the prefix in the filename.

Comment: If you select the files with the globbing pattern `*/` then each name in the variable will contain the slash as part of the name. To remove that terminating slash for your filename use `"${f%/}_appended.dat"`.

Comment: @janis Good point.  I will fix that as soon as I get a chance to sit in front of a proper keyboard.

Comment: John1024, this was actually meant as a comment for geokrowding; I think the fix I posted should solve the problem he still has.

Comment: @geokrowding Just to remove all doubt, if you have a directory named, say, `dir`, do you want the output file to be `./dir/_appended.dat` or `./dir`/dir_appended.dat` or `./dir_appended.dat`?

Comment: ./dir/_appended.dat but of course, it would be ideal to have the dir name prefix the filename, ie: 2006_appendee.dat in the 2006 folder.

Comment: @geokrowding  OK.  The answer is updated for the 'ideal' naming.

Comment: @John1024 Great. Is that / backslash after the f% an escape slash so that the actual slash does not get written? ie: "${f}${f%/}_appended.dat". Also, how about some rep cred, seeing as though i've given you props ;)

Comment: The `${f%/}` is an example of suffix removal.  The shell will remove whatever follows `%` from the end of variable `f`.  In our case, we are removing the final slash but suffix removal is far more general than that.  It is described in `man bash` under the heading _parameter expansion_.  P.S. Rep granted.